# Перенос записей с изображениями WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как можно перенести записи с вложениями/изображениями, мета данными от all in seo и с информацией ACF полей ? Нужны только записи..

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно перенести записи с вложениями/изображениями, мета данными от
>   all in seo и с информацией ACF полей ?

С помощью плагинов импорт-экспорта через csv.

Answer (score 0):

Связка плагинов WP All Export и WP All Import – достаточно мощный инструмент для такого переноса. Перенесет и изображения, и meta и acf.